# What is a seam (Seam-carving)

Tags: image, math, image-processing, seam-carving

I am reading the paper about seam carving for resizing an image.

Down on page 3 where they define a seam mathematically, I need help clarifying it.

The paper says that a seam is an 8-connected path of pixels. How can it be 8-connected if the pixel cannot be on the same row? Shouldn't it be 3-connected?

http://www.seamcarving.com/arik/imret.pdf 20 mb PDF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*8-connected* path of pixels [means](http://books.google.com/books?id=7gT1MhI1SbIC&pg=PA42&vq=region+filling) that all the 8 neighbors `o` around a pixel `x`:

```
ooo
oxo
ooo (1)
```

count in determining if the pixel is connected. so the `x` in

```
xoo
oxo
oox (2)
```

*are* 8-connected. in contrast, *4-connected* looks only at these 4 neighbors `o`:

```
 o
oxo
 o  (3)
```

under this scheme, the `x` in fig. 2 would *not* considered to be connected.

(there is no *3-connected* in computer graphics (that i know of))

this being said, the definition of a vertical seam:

> a vertical seam is an 8-connected path
>   of pixels in the image from top to
>   bottom, containing one, and only one,
>   pixel in each row of the image

seems quite easy to grasp to me. this:

```
x
 x
  x
```

is a vertical seam (because there is only one pixel per row), also:

```
x
 x
 x
```

this is; this:

```
x
 xx
  x
```

is not (because there are two pixel in row two).

hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It won't be 3 connected, it would be 6 connected but since there is nothing called 6 connected path, this is called 8-connected

(The '6' is referring to the 6 *potential* neighbours of a given pixel - 3 in the row above and 3 in the row below:)

```
xxx
 o
xxx
```